# NServiceBus Routing not working based on Assembly for generic types

Tags: .net-core, messaging, nservicebus

I have a scenario where I am sending a generic Command like: AddRequest.

When I configure routing using Assembly, it doesn't work (error: no destination specified):
`routeSettings.RouteToEndpoint(assembly, "App2.Endpoint");`
However the command gets sent successfully when configuring routing via type:

```
  var genericType = Type.GetType("SharedApp.AddRequest`1[[SharedApp,MyObject]],SharedApp");
   routeSettings.RouteToEndpoint(genericType, "App2.Endpoint");
```

Is something wrong/missing while configuring it via assembly ?

Answer (score 1):

When NServiceBus scans the assembly it looks for message types but all it finds is an open generic type `AddRequest<T>`.When you send a message, you send an instance of `AddRequest<MyObject>` which is a closed generic type, so different from the one discovered.

Unfortunately NServiceBus routing system is not aware of generic types and uses type equality to determine the route. Because of that it does not know where to sent `AddRequest<MyObject>`.

The reason why NServiceBus routing system has been designed this way is it already uses one mechanism for group route registration which is based on assembly and namespace. You can register one route for a set of types provided they are defined in same assembly and/or namespace. If you introduced yet another mechanism for grouping e.g. based on generic types or based on type inheritance (i.e. route for base type is used for derived types) we would end up in a situation where a type can have multiple routes associated with no clear way to pick one over the others.